# Mysql create view with progressively increment a datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, window-functions

I would like to create a view between two tables in mysql.

tbl1

```
| id_tbl1 | start_date          | delay | 
+---------+---------------------+-------+
|    1    | 2019-10-11 10:00:00 |  30   |
|    2    | 2019-10-12 18:00:00 |  0    |
```

tbl2

```
| id_tbl2 | id_tbl1 | user   | 
+---------+------------------+
|    1    |    1    |  Andy  |
|    2    |    1    |  Luke  |
|    3    |    2    |  Joe   |
|    4    |    1    |  Susy  |
|    5    |    2    |  Rick  |
```

I would like to progressively increment a datetime field by adding the value of the delay field.
The result should be this

view1

```
| id_tbl1 | user  | start_date       |
+---------+-------+------------------+
|    1    | Andy  | 2019-10-11 10:00:00 |
|    1    | Luke  | 2019-10-11 10:00:30 |
|    1    | Susy  | 2019-10-11 10:01:00 |
|    2    | Joe   | 2019-10-12 18:00:00 |
|    2    | Rick  | 2019-10-12 18:00:00 |
```

EDIT-
I would like to increase the seconds

Is it possible to do this?
How could I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could adress this with a `join` and `row_number()`:

```
select 
    t1.id_tbl1,
    t2.usr,
    date_add(
        t1.start_date, 
        interval (t1.delay * (row_number() over(partition by t1.id_tbl1 order by t2.id_tbl2 ) - 1)) second
    ) start_date
from tbl1 t1
inner join tbl2 t2 on t1.id_tbl1 = t2.id_tbl1
```

Note : `user` is not a good pick for a column name since it might clash with a reserved word. I changed it to `usr`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cDgNs1z1jLeeBxMZFUH9cb/0)**:

```
with 
    tbl1 as (
        select 1 id_tbl1, '2019-10-11 10:00' start_date, 30 delay from dual
        union all select 2, '2019-10-12 18:00', 0 from dual
    ),
    tbl2 as (
        select 1 id_tbl2, 1 id_tbl1, 'Andy' usr from dual
        union all select 2, 1, 'Luke' from dual
        union all select 3, 2, 'Joe' from dual
        union all select 4, 1, 'Susy' from dual
        union all select 5, 2, 'Rick' from dual
    )
select 
    t1.id_tbl1,
    t2.usr,
    date_add(
        t1.start_date, 
        interval (t1.delay * (row_number() over(partition by t1.id_tbl1 order by t2.id_tbl2 ) - 1)) second
    ) start_date
from tbl1 t1
inner join tbl2 t2 on t1.id_tbl1 = t2.id_tbl1;

| id_tbl1 | usr  | start_date          |
| ------- | ---- | ------------------- |
| 1       | Andy | 2019-10-11 10:00:00 |
| 1       | Luke | 2019-10-11 10:00:30 |
| 1       | Susy | 2019-10-11 10:01:00 |
| 2       | Joe  | 2019-10-12 18:00:00 |
| 2       | Rick | 2019-10-12 18:00:00 |
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, I'd like to add seconds. See my edit

Comment: @PaoloRossi: for some reason I initially gave you a solution for Oracle. I just changed it for mysql (I tested it and it runs fine)!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with mysql 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

here's your query, you can add your delay column as `interval` for your `start_date` field.

```
select t1.id_tbl1 , t1.user
    , case when t1.id_tbl2 = 1 then t1.start_date
        else t1.start_date + interval t2.delay * (id_tbl2 - 1) second end
from tbl2 t1
left join tbl1 t2 on t1.id_tbl1 = t2.id_tbl1
```

or since you are creating a view, you may want to join a variable.

```
select t1.id_tbl1 , t1.user
    , t1.start_date 
            + interval t2.delay * (@curRow:=@curRow + 1) second
            - interval t2.delay second
from tbl2 t1
left join tbl1 t2 on t1.id_tbl1 = t2.id_tbl1 
join (select @curRow := 0) r;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, I'd like to add seconds. See my edit

Comment: This works, but only as long as `id_tbl2` starts at `1`.

Comment: id_tbl2 may not always start at 1

Comment: if you are using mysql 8.0, deduct the row_number()

Comment: @PaoloRossi, or you can` join (select @curRow := 0) r;` since you are creating a view

Comment: dpends on your data. if theres no null. values. led join is ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201195/discussion-between-paolo-rossi-and-).